# How to clear apt-conf list options in apt-get command line options

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm trying to use the [`apt-conf` `#clear` syntax](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/apt.conf.5.html) to clear the `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs` options on command-line `apt-get`, but I haven't had any luck. I've tried stuff like `apt-get -o DPkg::Pre-Install-Packages='#clear'`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late, but i used something like

```
cat <<EOF | sudo apt-get -c /dev/stdin install <package>
#clear DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs;
EOF
```

Using option "-c" of apt-get to specify the configuration file to use.

See apt-get(8) por option "-c" and apt.conf(5), section "Description", for the order in which an APT tool read the configuration files.

Although the trick of using "/dev/stdin" looks very "esoteric" to me.